# Getting value within any time of the day

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am creating an attendance system and i want to automatically change the subject based on the time of the day. I have a table consist of subject name, start time, end time and its day. I have a question, is it possible to automatically get the value of a row based on specific time and day?

For example the current time is 12:45 PM and the day is Tuesday. [This is my sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU1tr.png). Then the output will be Principles of OS.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql to get the name the current day use

DAYNAME(date)

and compare it to your sub_day column in selection